# How to change class named active into link's active attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using superfish for menu.Since it doesn't come with `active class` to denote current page tab.I added the following javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var path = window.location.pathname.split('/');
path = path[path.length-1];
if (path !== undefined) {
  $("ul.sf-menu")
    .find("a[href$='" + path + "']") // gets all links that match the href
    .parents('li')  // gets all list items that are ancestors of the link
    .children('a')  // walks down one level from all selected li's
    .addClass('active');
}
</script>
```

I also added a class named active in css as the script requires.

```
.sf-menu a.active{
   margin-top:-5px;
   height: 51px; 
   padding-top: 15px;
   z-index: 100;
   background-color:#072438;
 }
```

It worked just fine.However for some reason I would like to change the css from

```
a.active into a:active
```

But how do I change this part in javascript to suit the css please?

```
.addClass('active');
```

Comment: Short answer is that, as far as I know, you can't set CSS pseudo-classes with jQuery (or JavaScript for that matter).

Comment: You'll have to refactor your CSS a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add a `pseudo-class` on an element using javascript in the same way that you can't add a `pseudo-class` in an inline `style=''` attribute.

What you can do is alter your stylesheet with javascript to add the rule you want:

`document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('a:active { color: red; }'`, 0);